# Отправка заявки OpenCart

Tags: email, opencart

Здравствуйте!

Вопрос короткий, но все же вопрос. При отправке заявки со стандартной(переделанной) темы OpenCart 2.3.0.2 заявка отлично проходит на почту админу, а как реализовать отправку и админу и пользователю сообщение(можно одно и тоже)?

Спасибо за любую информацию!

Answer (score 0):

Прочитайте [**Система Событий (Event) в OpenCart.**](https://freecart.pro/forum/blogs/entry/12-sistema-sobyitiy-event-v-opencart-chast-1-iz-3-obrabotka-sobyitiy/) или [**СИСТЕМА СОБЫТИЙ В OPENCART 2.X: КАК ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ EVENT.**](https://nikita-sp.com.ua/2015/12/sistema-sobyitiy-opencart-2-ispolzovat-event.html) Там, в статьях, описан практически ваш случай, только другие контроллеры задействованы. Если захочется добавки, то вот - [**10 Secrets that will make you a master of Opencart Events**](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=cms/blog/info&blog_id=174)